# Why is margin used for sticky positioning

Tags: css, css-position, sticky

See this example

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
}

.container section h2 {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding-top: calc(1em / 6 * 5);
  padding-bottom: calc(1em / 6 * 5);
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <section>
    <h2>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi perferendis animi sint ducimus ullam earum aliquid consequatur dolores delectus. Ex unde mollitia placeat vitae incidunt voluptatibus qui earum deleniti cupiditate.</p>
    <p>Delectus tenetur alias numquam magni! Magnam perspiciatis ducimus vero facere, totam non odit accusamus nisi dicta deserunt distinctio minus rerum maiores magni, eligendi vitae, a omnis autem deleniti quaerat officiis.</p>
    <p>At iusto architecto aut laudantium nisi quod praesentium dolorem delectus repudiandae soluta enim consequatur porro, quam nemo cumque sint aspernatur laborum deleniti. Molestiae, dolor saepe quisquam suscipit quod aliquid dolore.</p>
    <p>Autem perspiciatis ipsam molestias inventore nulla? Nostrum voluptatibus unde autem est. Minus quam molestias ullam cupiditate laborum eius. Nulla unde repellat mollitia dolore aliquam aspernatur velit sit dolorem quibusdam repudiandae.</p>
    <p>Illum dicta inventore, adipisci veritatis nobis placeat ab quas nihil est, incidunt reprehenderit quibusdam odio non autem expedita ex quos dolorum? Et fuga facere obcaecati laborum fugiat praesentium, aliquid in.</p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h2>Quisquam, consequuntur quibusdam.</h2>
    <p>Similique quas impedit est iure quisquam! Hic cumque illo ipsam, itaque fugiat, et commodi enim aliquam quos minima nihil quae sapiente vero amet magni. Ipsum sint maiores necessitatibus eos optio!</p>
    <p>Odit, assumenda. Non harum perspiciatis delectus sint, molestias nostrum laboriosam labore accusantium mollitia assumenda officia omnis rerum dolorum veritatis impedit sapiente, ea, reprehenderit voluptatem! Minus dolor aspernatur illo velit sit.</p>
    <p>Recusandae qui repellat debitis non aliquam ea quod quam, magnam ipsum placeat vitae? Ut, nisi eos consequatur voluptatibus sit nulla corporis omnis quae repellendus, voluptates sapiente, labore quibusdam deleniti molestias.</p>
    <p>Assumenda dolor ex, numquam reprehenderit ipsa, nihil aperiam reiciendis aliquam eaque et harum mollitia fugit amet repellendus! Suscipit, veritatis cum. Corporis saepe, adipisci officia numquam obcaecati voluptatem. Fugit, amet quia!</p>
    <p>Fugiat, quaerat harum id aliquam repellat dolor assumenda eos provident reprehenderit excepturi! Tempore nisi animi sequi repellat perferendis deserunt incidunt natus quae harum minima, fuga id repellendus? Amet, beatae accusamus?</p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h2>Eos, harum nobis.</h2>
    <p>Delectus, eius provident vel hic veritatis quidem cumque unde ratione quia eaque non iusto. Ad veniam quidem molestias minima, labore, pariatur, tempore qui sequi quaerat suscipit itaque animi adipisci tempora!</p>
    <p>Atque dolor earum distinctio sit labore quae, animi pariatur quibusdam voluptatem velit. Quisquam ad, cum repellendus enim illo esse dolor qui perferendis voluptate in, beatae aspernatur at doloremque exercitationem assumenda.</p>
    <p>Sunt unde veritatis repudiandae culpa ipsum. Vero ipsam eveniet voluptatum quis, necessitatibus adipisci nisi, ad excepturi mollitia temporibus eaque repellendus blanditiis rerum itaque, consequatur ea eligendi ullam nam officia. Veniam.</p>
    <p>Nihil vitae aut magni, repellat itaque consequatur corporis praesentium libero aperiam quasi ea quaerat quisquam, repudiandae quis ipsam ratione totam quod? Quasi, debitis! Harum illo exercitationem totam debitis sunt nulla!</p>
    <p>Pariatur ex est hic nesciunt ullam et molestias ducimus consectetur, odio maxime voluptas quos magnam asperiores, quaerat totam facilis perspiciatis id ut facere nam doloremque quis dolores distinctio iure! Nobis.</p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h2>Minima, magni minus.</h2>
    <p>Rem ullam doloribus voluptatem suscipit minima perspiciatis adipisci, iure dolorem? Voluptatibus vitae nulla repudiandae consequatur ut culpa rem magni quia fugiat provident quae explicabo recusandae non rerum, saepe porro. Dolorum?</p>
    <p>Mollitia amet neque architecto necessitatibus reiciendis earum esse veritatis, sunt magni repudiandae animi asperiores eligendi veniam non, nam quis, nobis aspernatur odit modi sapiente velit? Eum quis facere quidem esse!</p>
    <p>Ea omnis atque similique reiciendis, incidunt voluptatem aliquam totam qui temporibus velit distinctio corrupti excepturi, cupiditate fuga optio natus illo aut obcaecati minima sint, dolorum provident? Architecto nisi iure debitis.</p>
    <p>Odit impedit cum magnam pariatur corporis voluptatum numquam quae rerum qui nesciunt, architecto, voluptas culpa dolore doloremque. Eius vitae quasi corporis ipsum facilis voluptate. Beatae repellat molestiae eum autem nobis.</p>
    <p>Nulla consectetur, recusandae error dolorum ad enim vel placeat esse, voluptatum est, et dignissimos autem laudantium ut. Neque voluptate vitae quasi veniam dolore excepturi, atque exercitationem in nihil eius velit.</p>
  </section>
</div>
```

If you scroll down, you will see, that all the `<h2>` elements are sticky to the containing `<section>` elements as they ought to. But … the h1 does not overlay all of the static `<p>`  element below the sticky `<h2>`. The amount of *'non-overlapping'* is exactly the bottom margin (`0.83em` at least on FF and Chrome).

[image: Show the non overlap of sticky <h2> over <p> because of margin-bottom if <h2>]

As far as I can tell, I can only prevent this issue by assigning `margin-bottom: 0` to the `<h2>`. But I don't want that, because then I lose margin-collapsing with the following `<p>` elements. (Yeah, I know, I could somehow get around with this, but I refuse to)

The `<h2>` has collapsing `margin-top` with the section (if there is defined any), as long as the element is not *'sticky'*, but it has non collapsing `margin-bottom`, if scrolled, so that it is sticky.

## Margin-collapse, when <h2> is NOT sticky

> [image: margin-collapse, when <h2> is NOT sticky]

## No margin-collapse, when <h2> IS sticky

> [image: No margin-collapse, when <h2> IS sticky]

1. Why does this happen?
2. Is it like this in the spec?
3. Who decided on this?
4. Is this useful in any case I can't think of right now?
5. Is there any workaround that doesn't involve setting `margin-bottom` of `<h2>` to zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's in the specifiaition here: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-position-3/#sticky-pos.

Here is the relevant part:

> When computing containement of the stickily positioned element within its containing block, **margins on the stickily positioned element are taken into account**.

This is somehow logical because our sticky element will behave as relative and its margin will affect the height of the containing block so it should also be considered.

Consider the example where the sticky element is the only element inside the containing block

```css
.wrapper {
  border:2px solid;
}

.wrapper > div {
  position:sticky;
  top:0;
  height:50px;
  margin-bottom:150vh;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

There should be no sticky behavior in this case because our element (with its margin) is already touching the edge of the containing block.

---

This said, one workaround is to visually increase the space for our element while keeping the same distance between the other element. To do so we add a hidden element with a specific height and we rectify with a negative margin.

Here is an example:

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
}

.container section h2 {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding-top: calc(1em / 6 * 5);
  padding-bottom: calc(1em / 6 * 5);
  background-color: #fff;
}

.container section {
  margin-bottom:calc(1.5 * -0.83em);
}
.container section:after {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  height:0.83em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <section>
    <h2>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi perferendis animi sint ducimus ullam earum aliquid consequatur dolores delectus. Ex unde mollitia placeat vitae incidunt voluptatibus qui earum deleniti cupiditate.</p>
    <p>Delectus tenetur alias numquam magni! Magnam perspiciatis ducimus vero facere, totam non odit accusamus nisi dicta deserunt distinctio minus rerum maiores magni, eligendi vitae, a omnis autem deleniti quaerat officiis.</p>
    <p>At iusto architecto aut laudantium nisi quod praesentium dolorem delectus repudiandae soluta enim consequatur porro, quam nemo cumque sint aspernatur laborum deleniti. Molestiae, dolor saepe quisquam suscipit quod aliquid dolore.</p>
    <p>Autem perspiciatis ipsam molestias inventore nulla? Nostrum voluptatibus unde autem est. Minus quam molestias ullam cupiditate laborum eius. Nulla unde repellat mollitia dolore aliquam aspernatur velit sit dolorem quibusdam repudiandae.</p>
    <p>Illum dicta inventore, adipisci veritatis nobis placeat ab quas nihil est, incidunt reprehenderit quibusdam odio non autem expedita ex quos dolorum? Et fuga facere obcaecati laborum fugiat praesentium, aliquid in.</p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h2>Quisquam, consequuntur quibusdam.</h2>
    <p>Similique quas impedit est iure quisquam! Hic cumque illo ipsam, itaque fugiat, et commodi enim aliquam quos minima nihil quae sapiente vero amet magni. Ipsum sint maiores necessitatibus eos optio!</p>
    <p>Odit, assumenda. Non harum perspiciatis delectus sint, molestias nostrum laboriosam labore accusantium mollitia assumenda officia omnis rerum dolorum veritatis impedit sapiente, ea, reprehenderit voluptatem! Minus dolor aspernatur illo velit sit.</p>
    <p>Recusandae qui repellat debitis non aliquam ea quod quam, magnam ipsum placeat vitae? Ut, nisi eos consequatur voluptatibus sit nulla corporis omnis quae repellendus, voluptates sapiente, labore quibusdam deleniti molestias.</p>
    <p>Assumenda dolor ex, numquam reprehenderit ipsa, nihil aperiam reiciendis aliquam eaque et harum mollitia fugit amet repellendus! Suscipit, veritatis cum. Corporis saepe, adipisci officia numquam obcaecati voluptatem. Fugit, amet quia!</p>
    <p>Fugiat, quaerat harum id aliquam repellat dolor assumenda eos provident reprehenderit excepturi! Tempore nisi animi sequi repellat perferendis deserunt incidunt natus quae harum minima, fuga id repellendus? Amet, beatae accusamus?</p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h2>Eos, harum nobis.</h2>
    <p>Delectus, eius provident vel hic veritatis quidem cumque unde ratione quia eaque non iusto. Ad veniam quidem molestias minima, labore, pariatur, tempore qui sequi quaerat suscipit itaque animi adipisci tempora!</p>
    <p>Atque dolor earum distinctio sit labore quae, animi pariatur quibusdam voluptatem velit. Quisquam ad, cum repellendus enim illo esse dolor qui perferendis voluptate in, beatae aspernatur at doloremque exercitationem assumenda.</p>
    <p>Sunt unde veritatis repudiandae culpa ipsum. Vero ipsam eveniet voluptatum quis, necessitatibus adipisci nisi, ad excepturi mollitia temporibus eaque repellendus blanditiis rerum itaque, consequatur ea eligendi ullam nam officia. Veniam.</p>
    <p>Nihil vitae aut magni, repellat itaque consequatur corporis praesentium libero aperiam quasi ea quaerat quisquam, repudiandae quis ipsam ratione totam quod? Quasi, debitis! Harum illo exercitationem totam debitis sunt nulla!</p>
    <p>Pariatur ex est hic nesciunt ullam et molestias ducimus consectetur, odio maxime voluptas quos magnam asperiores, quaerat totam facilis perspiciatis id ut facere nam doloremque quis dolores distinctio iure! Nobis.</p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h2>Minima, magni minus.</h2>
    <p>Rem ullam doloribus voluptatem suscipit minima perspiciatis adipisci, iure dolorem? Voluptatibus vitae nulla repudiandae consequatur ut culpa rem magni quia fugiat provident quae explicabo recusandae non rerum, saepe porro. Dolorum?</p>
    <p>Mollitia amet neque architecto necessitatibus reiciendis earum esse veritatis, sunt magni repudiandae animi asperiores eligendi veniam non, nam quis, nobis aspernatur odit modi sapiente velit? Eum quis facere quidem esse!</p>
    <p>Ea omnis atque similique reiciendis, incidunt voluptatem aliquam totam qui temporibus velit distinctio corrupti excepturi, cupiditate fuga optio natus illo aut obcaecati minima sint, dolorum provident? Architecto nisi iure debitis.</p>
    <p>Odit impedit cum magnam pariatur corporis voluptatum numquam quae rerum qui nesciunt, architecto, voluptas culpa dolore doloremque. Eius vitae quasi corporis ipsum facilis voluptate. Beatae repellat molestiae eum autem nobis.</p>
    <p>Nulla consectetur, recusandae error dolorum ad enim vel placeat esse, voluptatum est, et dignissimos autem laudantium ut. Neque voluptate vitae quasi veniam dolore excepturi, atque exercitationem in nihil eius velit.</p>
  </section>
</div>
```

You should simply pay attention to complex situation that involves margin-collapsing with the last child since adding this extra element will disable it. You may need to increase more the negative margin.

Comment: Ok, you are right. But I think it's a misuse of the margin property. The stickily element is positions relatively. This should allow for margin-collapse. They should have introduced a new property, mybe `sticky-margin`!

Comment: @yunzen this will probably change later, as you can see in the spec there is at least 6 issues and one related to margin collapsing between sticky element and containing block so probably both margin will collapse and we will no more have this issue

Comment: @yunzen you can participate on some issues and discuss with others here : https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/. This is how some decision are made ;)  the working group is open and listen to developer

Comment: Let me ask you a personal question. Did you ever participated in the discussion?

Comment: @yunzen no, I simply check few issues from time to time to see if there is new features o new decisions made so that I am aware about what will happen in the near future. I never found something that worth be added as an issue or suggestion. Probably will do one day ;)

Answer (score 0):

See my screenshot to understand why with your `h2` don't go above your last line.

Here in blue you can see you `<section>`

[image]

And here your `h2`

[image]

So, your `h2` can't go above the last line because margin push up your title.

EDIT: If you need absolutely this space under your `h2`, you can put margin-top to the first `<p>` after an `h2`...

```
h2 + p:first-of-type{
  margin-top:10px;
}
```

Comment: I know this all. Your answer is just a different way of asking the same question as I did. And for your edit, I have to put `h2 { margin-bottom: 0}` beforehand

Comment: Yes , I would said, to replace margin....
I think margins have the same effect as the position absolute because the element are no longer in the flow with position sticky and absolute